# How do I add padding with Container?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to make on top some padding but how to do this with Container?

```
    JFrame frame = super.screen.getFullScreenWindow();
    //Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    //JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

    // Make sure the content pane is transparent
    if (contentPane instanceof JComponent) {
        ((JComponent)contentPane).setOpaque(false);
    } 
    else {
      // ??
    }

    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
    //frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

### Output

```
 [javac] symbol  : method setBorder(javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder)
 [javac] location: class java.awt.Container 
 [javac] contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
 [javac]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [Container#getInsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getInsets%28%29), although you should be using Swing components.

Answer (score 15):

Can't you simply add a JPanel to contain everything and set empty border on that ?

```
 JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
 containerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
 containerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 //panel to test
 JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
 testPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);        
 containerPanel.add(testPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

 //assuming you are extending JFrame
 getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 getContentPane().add(containerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transparency" - please edit your question with what you tried and what was the issue

Answer (score 2):

- `JFrame / Frame` and its `ContentPane` doesn't implements `Borders`, this is prehistoric `Componenet`
- put directly there `JPanel` with `EmptyBorders`
- for `Java5` and higher isn't required to call for `ContentPane` (only for `setBackground:-)`, you can directly add `JComponents` to the `JFrame#add(myJComponent)`, notice `Swing Top-Level Containers` have got implemented `BorderLayout` by default

Comment: JPanel i tried like above edit. But i do not have transparent container while using JPanel instead of Container.

Answer (score 0):

don't you prefer to use swing ? Components have a method to add margins. Swing is far better than the obsolete awt library.